# How to access a class annotated @SystemApi in android?

Tags: android, android-service

I am trying to access abstract class from android service package which is annotated with `@SystemApi`. All my efforts were futile and no help available either.

Can anyone tell me how to access/extend that class? And what is the significance of `@SystemApi`?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you cannot do that as a 3rd party application.
Unless you can build with AOSP and put your app in the firmware.